# Find the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)2^k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

On a discrete mathematics past paper, I must find the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)2^k$.
Could I have a hint/hints for approaching this problem, please?

NB: the preceding problem was as follows.

Let $f(x)=x!$ be the factorial of a non-negative integer x.  Compute $\Delta f(x)$ (where $\Delta f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$) and use the result to find the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot k!$$
I managed to solve this problem, and since the problem I have asked about above is part of the same question, I tried to use a similar approach.  That is, I tried to find a function $f$, such that $\Delta f(x)=k(k+1)2^k$; however this was to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(k)=2^{k+1}(k^2-k+2)$. Then,$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k+1)2^k&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(f(k)-f(k-1)\right)\\&=f(n)-f(0)\\&=2^{n+1}(n^2-n+2)-4\end{align}$$

---

In general, let $g(k)=2^{k+1}(a_2k^2+(a_1-2a_2)k+a_0-a_1+3a_2)$. Then,
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_2k^2+a_1k+a_0)2^k&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(g(k)-g(k-1))\\&=g(n)-g(0)\\&=2^{n+1}(a_2n^2+(a_1-2a_2)n+a_0-a_1+3a_2)-2(a_0-a_1+3a_2)\end{align}$$

To find $g(k)$, setting $$(a_2k^2+a_1k+a_0)2^k=2^{k+1}(b_2k^2+b_1k+b_0)-2^{k}(b_2(k-1)^2+b_1(k-1)+b_0)$$ works to find $b_2=a_2,b_1=a_1-2a_2,b_0=a_0-a_1+3a_2$.

Comment: How to find the initial form of $f(k)$. For example what if the summation were $$\sum_{k=1}^nk(4+k)2^k$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: I added a bit. For your example, we get $a=k+1,b=2,c=-1$.

Comment: For $$\sum 2^k(a_0+a_1k+a_2k^2)$$ should we start with $$2^k(b_0+b_1k+b_2k^2)$$ ?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: I added a bit. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{hint:}$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k+1)r^k = \frac{1}{r^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k+1)r^{k+2} =  \frac{1}{r^2}\dfrac{d}{dr^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}r^{k+2} =  \frac{1}{r^2}\dfrac{d}{dr^2}r^2\sum_{k=1}^{n}r^{k} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nk(k+1)x^k$$

$$S_n-xS_{n-1}=1(1+1)x^1+2(2+1)x^2+\cdots+r(r+1)x^r+(r+1)(r+2)x^{r+1}+\cdots+n(n+1)x^n$$

$$-[1(1+1)x^2+2(2+1)x^3+\cdots+r(r+1)x^{r+1}+\cdots+n(n+1)x^{n+1}]$$

$$\implies S_n-xS_{n-1}=2x-n(n+1)x^{n+1}+[\sum_{r=2}^nx^r\{r(r+1)-(r-1)r\}]$$

$$=2x-n(n+1)x^{n+1}+2[\sum_{r=2}^n rx^r]$$

Again let $$T=\sum_{r=2}^n rx^r$$

Use $T-x\cdot T$